# tmux echoing from a script on every pane switch

Tags: bash, plugins, zsh, tmux

i am new to tmux and scripting and trying to add branch name while inside vim on the tmux status bar.
the code seems to work fine until i switch/create pane in tmux.
[image: output from script]

every time i switch or create a new pane i see the echo result from the script.
its only happening when switching/creating pane but works fine while creating a new window.

https://imgur.com/a/LJtfg63

here is the script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

get_git_branch() {
    local branch
    if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2>&1)
        echo "$branch"
    else
        echo ""
    fi
}

clock() {
        date "+%a %e %b %-I:%M %p"
}

no_branch_status(){
  echo "#[fg=colour072]session(#[fg=colour35]#S#[fg=colour072]) #[fg=colour072]| #[fg=colour067,bold]$(clock)#[default]"
}

current_dir="$(tmux display-message -p "#{pane_current_path}")"
cd "$current_dir" || exit 1

if [ "$(tmux display-message -p "#{pane_current_command}")" = "vim" ]; then
    git_branch=$(get_git_branch)
    if [ -n "$git_branch" ]; then
      echo "#[fg=colour072]session(#[fg=colour35]#S#[fg=colour072]) #[fg=colour223]  $git_branch  #[default]"
    else
                no_branch_status
    fi
else
    # Echo the current session along with the ASCII clock
    no_branch_status
fi
```

and thats how i am using it in tmuxconf `set -g status-right '#(~/.tmux/plugins/mine/vim-git-branch.sh)'`

---

Operating System: MacOS

tmux Version: 3.3a

shell: Zsh

Comment: @pynexj removed https://imgur.com/a/LJtfg63

Comment: just tried and it worked quite well for me (also on macos with tmux 3.3a).

Comment: @pynexj you tried switching pane ?

Comment: yes i tried switching between panes (in the same window) back and forth for a few times.

Comment: is there alternate way to set tmux status instead of using echo ?